# Javascript ES6 replace null with empty string in a nested array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a dynamic array which can have n number of sections/fields as below.

```
[
    {
        "id": "section-1",
        "fields": [{
                "id": "field1",
                "value": "A1"
            }, {
                "id": "field2",
                "value": null
            }
        ]
    }, {
        "id": "section-2",
        "fields": [{
                "id": "field3",
                "value": null
            }, {
                "id": "field4",
                "value": null
            }
        ]
    }, {
        "id": "section-3",
        "fields": [{
                "id": "field5",
                "value": "A5"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Can I use ES6 to update any null values to empty string in this array. So the output would be the same exact structure replacing any `"value": null` with `"value": ""`

Answer (score 2):

Nested `forEach()` calls:

```js
const data = [{
  "id": "section-1",
  "fields": [{
    "id": "field1",
    "value": "A1"
  }, {
    "id": "field2",
    "value": null
  }]
}, {
  "id": "section-2",
  "fields": [{
    "id": "field3",
    "value": null
  }, {
    "id": "field4",
    "value": null
  }]
}, {
  "id": "section-3",
  "fields": [{
    "id": "field5",
    "value": "A5"
  }]
}];

data.forEach(section => section.fields.forEach(field => {
  if (field.value === null) {
    field.value = "";
  }
}));

console.log(data);
```

Comment: This will not work w/o a code change when new props are added to the field object.  JSON parsing with the reviver function seems a good way to do this as suggested by @DecPK

Comment: The question specifically asked about the `value` property, not any properties that are null. So I didn't write a general function that scans all the properties.

Comment: Building on [the anwser from @DecPK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76499622/15167500), it is possible to modify only the null value of the `value` property and replace it with an empty string by using the following code: `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj), (key, value) => key === "value" && value === null ? "" : value)`. Actually, you just need to use the `key` attribute received in the function.

Comment: @rozsazoltan I don't see the point, unless you're not allowed to modify the objects in place.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a pretty simple neat trick using [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) and [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) using [`reviver parameter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#the_reviver_parameter) as:

> It will replace `null` with `""` doesn't matter how nested object it is.

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj), (key, value) => value === null ? "": value)
```

```js
const obj = [
    {
        "id": "section-1",
        "fields": [{
            "id": "field1",
            "value": "A1"
        }, {
            "id": "field2",
            "value": null
        }
        ]
    }, {
        "id": "section-2",
        "fields": [{
            "id": "field3",
            "value": null
        }, {
            "id": "field4",
            "value": null
        }
        ]
    }, {
        "id": "section-3",
        "fields": [{
            "id": "field5",
            "value": "A5"
        }
        ]
    }
]

const result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj), (key, value) => value === null ? "": value)
console.log(result);
```